# symfony : forms and primary keys

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, primary-key

I have a form and when I want to set the primary key, I have an error 'Invalid' after the form's validation.

My widget :

```
$this->widgetSchema['nud'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();
```

And my validator :

```
'nud'            => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('nud')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('nud'), 'required' => false)),
```

I have kept the validator generated by symfony but I have change the widget because symfony hase generated an inputHidden and the value which I want to enter isn't in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's needed to do is just change default validator!

```
'name'      => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 50, 'required' => false))
```